# Merging existing CSS classes into new CSS classes to get the same design output but with less classes

Tags: css, accordion

I have a CSS-stylesheet that contains several classes to style accordion elements. Due to several restrictions in the editor software I am forced to use, I need to embed other accordions via JavaScript.
This script only allow me to use three CSS classes to style the accordion. I would like to give them a similar style like those created by the editor.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to 'break down' the following multiple classes (those from the editor software) to the three new classes (those for the JS) to get a similar style of the accordions.

> Existing CSS classes from the editor:

```
<cc:*> Accordeon </cc:*>

.sqracc {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
}
.sqracc .sqracchead {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid <cc:print value="site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sqracc .sqracchead:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.sqracc .sqracchead div {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 32px;
  border-top: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  border-left: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  border-right: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  cursor: inherit;
  float: left;
  background: #ffffff url(<cc:print value="&accclosed.svg.filename">) 10px 50% no-repeat;
  min-width: 30%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.sqracc .sqracccontainer {
  display: none;
}
.sqracc.sqraccopen .sqracccontainer {
  display: block;
}
.sqracc.sqraccopen .sqracchead div {
  background-image: url(<cc:print value="&accopen.svg.filename">);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sqracc .sqracchead {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
}
```

> And this are my new classes:

```
.bar {
}

.baropen {
}

.content {
}
```

> I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
.balken {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 32px;
  border-top: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  border-left: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  border-right: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder">;
  cursor: inherit;
  float: left;
  background: #ffffff url(<cc:print value="&accclosed.svg.filename">) 10px 50% no-repeat;
  min-width: 30%;
}

.balkenopen { 
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(<cc:print value="&accopen.svg.filename">)no-repeat;

}
.inhalt {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[EDIT]

> here is the JS which I embedded in the code of the editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<cc:print value="&ddac.url">">">

</script>
<cc:if cond="&para.properties.design.ddaccor.first.default.open">
<cc:set value="0" obj="para.properties.design.ddaccor.first.default.open"></cc:if>
<script type="text/javascript">
<cc:if cond="&topic.properties.design.ddaccor.scrolltop"><cc:set value="true" obj="scrollstatus"><cc:else><cc:set value="false" obj="scrollstatus"></cc:if>
<cc:if cond="&topic.properties.design.ddaccor.default.open gt 0"><cc:set value="&topic.properties.design.ddaccor.default.open-1" obj="topic.properties.design.ddaccor.default.open"></cc:if>
//Initialize first Default Open :
ddaccordion.init({
headerclass: "bar", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
contentclass: "content", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
revealtype: "click", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false 
defaultexpanded: [<cc:print value="&topic.properties.design.ddaccor.default.open">], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc]. [] denotes no content.
onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
scrolltoheader: <cc:print value="&scrollstatus">, //scroll to header each time after it's been expanded by the user?
persiststate: false, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
toggleclass: ["bar", "baropen"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
togglehtml: ["none", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
animatespeed: "<cc:print value='&topic.properties.design.ddaccor.slide.speed'>", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
oninit:function(expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
    //do nothing
    },
onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
    //do nothing
    }
})
</script>
```

As you can see this script have given classes. And I cant figure out how to edit those classes in order that they create a similar style like the accordion style classes in the editor CSS.

There is only one CSS file for the whole page.
[/EDIT]

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: Hey Alla Mh, thanks for your comment. which code would you like to see? the JS?

Comment: No, I meant the HTML

Comment: I would love to but this annoying editor I need to work with use CCML language and the code is spread over many files. but here is some output code which create the accordion (created by the editor) `<div class="sqracc sqraccopen">
       <div class="sqracchead">
  <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sqracccontainer">
  <div>
 <div class="sqrpara">
<h2 id="724817a7640bb6402">TESTTEST</h2>
<p style="">TESTTEST</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> `

Comment: I'm sorry, the readability is not good in the comments. And its a little bit difficult to explain. The source code, which this editor software use to create a website is hard to read and confusing for me. But I try to give you all information you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this type of editor but you have two ways to achieve what you want:
**Solution#1:**
If there is a reference for the editor css 
just put it before your customized css reference e.ge

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="editor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="YourCustomizedStyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will make your style override the editor style
**Solution#2:**
Use `!important` on your CSS (I do not prefer this way) like this:

```
.balken {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  cursor: hand !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 32px !important;
  border-top: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder"> !important;
  border-left: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder"> !important;
  border-right: 1px solid <cc:print value="&site.properties.design.boxborder"> !important;
  cursor: inherit !important;
  float: left !important;
  background: #ffffff url(<cc:print value="&accclosed.svg.filename">) 10px 50% no-repeat !important;
  min-width: 30% !important;
}

.balkenopen { 
    cursor: hand !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    background-image: url(<cc:print value="&accopen.svg.filename">)no-repeat !important;

}
.inhalt {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
but I would like it vise versa, so that my customized css create the same style as the editor css.
(Like that the editor css override my custom css)

Comment: Just use your classes with the same way, you're welcome :)

Comment: oh and inside the editor css is the all the css for the whole page, not only for the accordions

Comment: then wrap the accordion with `div` and give it a `class` then style all elements under this class only to make sure that you will not affect anything else

Comment: just added the JS and some more information to my question.
I get what you're saying but I still dont get how I can 'get the style out of the editor css classes'. 
Because the editor css use 8 classes to create and style the accordions.
And the javascript only use 3 classes.
I need to 'break down' the css of the 8 classes into my new 3 classes to get the same style (which the editor creates with 8 classes) in my 3 classes.
But the editor use many sub/child classes and I haven't figured out yet how to press them into my 3 classes.
Thank you for your time and help, Alaa Mh :)